# How can one change the value of a variable in Android Application Class ?i

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose i have a Application class

```
public class AppConfig extends MultiDexApplication {
public static String DIR_NAME;
public final static String ANOTHER_DIR = DIR_NAME + File.separator() + "records" 

public static void createDirs(String dirName){
    DIR_NAME = dirName;

}
```

> When AppConfig.createDirs("test") is called from an Activity

It creates a folder named null.
While the expected behavior was a folder, with the name that was passed as parameter.

> So, how can one change the value of a variable in Android Application
>   Class ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change ANOTHER_DIR value update it in your static method.

```
public class AppConfig extends MultiDexApplication {
public static String DIR_NAME;
publicstatic String ANOTHER_DIR;

public static void createDirs(String dirName){
     ANOTHER_DIR = dirName + File.separator() +  "records" 

}
```

Comment: That seems to be the case, I will update you once I test it.